# done() function returning null ParseObject

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I want to delete a row in the table of database using ParseObject.But I am not able to do so as apparently the done() function is returning a null object.
Following is my **code for deletion**:

**"vex"** is the **table name** and **"objectId"** is the **objectId of the table**

```
  Button yes=(Button)layout.findViewById(R.id.byes);
    yes.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"inside yes!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Vex");
            query.whereEqualTo("objectId", objectId);
            query.getInBackground(objectId, new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
                @Override
                public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {

                    if (object == null) {
                        Log.d("vque", "The getFirst request failed.");
                    } else {
                        try {
                            object.delete();
                            object.saveInBackground();


                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Deleted Successuly.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                        } catch (ParseException e1) {
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }



                }
            });
}});
```

Comment: Are you sure about the names (case matters)? Do you get any `ParseException` when `object` is null?

Comment: Actually when I Toasted objectId I am getting null.May be that is the reason I am getting a Null Object.I don't understand why I am getting ObjectId as null.

Comment: Where is `objectId` defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 query.whereEqualTo("objectId", objectId);
```

Inspecting this point I found out that the objectId is null.Hence, this was returning a null ParseObject in the function done().

I was getting null objectId because i had used this line to retrieve the objectId.

```
String objectId=object.getString("objectId");
```

While I should have rather used:

```
String objectId=object.getObjectId();
```